# How to enlarge an SVG and keep its ratio

Tags: html, svg

I have this code

```html
<svg width="325" height="250" viewBox="20 40 2 555" style="outline: 1px solid #666;">
 <path data-map-id="1" style="fill: #d9534f" class="st3" d="M345.1,302.4V276c0-3.5,2.8-6.3,6.3-6.3h20.3v32.7H345.1z"/>
</svg>
```

I want this to appear much larger by %200. I read and tried several, what seems to be solutions, but I can't seem to get it it work. The goal is, when the user selects this 'block' the path is generated onto another page, but I need to increase the size - seems smple enough...right? Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried manipulating the width and height using css and inline style, but to no avail

Comment: cjhange `svg width="325" height="250"` to `svg width="650" height="500"`

Comment: I observe that you do not preserve the aspect ratio. While `width="325" height="250"` the viewBox is viewBox="20 40 **2 555**"  Why?

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks! Worked and I was able to manipulate t to the right size and position... BUT, of course, the width is messing with my webpage. Is there any way to contain the svg in a div and parent the width?

Comment: `with` and `height` are the same for all DOM objects. but you must first understand the importance of the `viewbox` if you want to understand the basis of using SVG elements

Answer (score 0):

> seems simple enough...right?

Just a Smop ([Small matter of programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming))

Now you did not give quite enough ground rules as to MWE (Minimal Working Exception)

Lets try to enlarge the source blob 200% to make the green one, and here is the correct way with those untold assumptions that

- 1. the centroids are the same
- 2. the widow stays the same
     (but note I had to push the envelope out 5 units to the right, to keep in viewport)

[image]

```html
<html><head></head><body>
<div>
<svg width="325" height="250" viewBox="25 40 2 555" style="outline: 1px solid #666;">

<--! new object width = 2 x (6.3+20.3) -->
<--! new Mx & H offset = 345.1-13.3 = 331.8 -->
<--! new object height = 2 x (32.7) -->
<--! new My offset = 302.4 + (65.4-12.6)/2 = 328.8 -->
<--! new V offset = 276 + 6.3 - (32.7/2) = 265.95 -->
<--! others generally X 200% -->


<path data-map-id="2" style="fill: #00ff00" class="st3" 
d="
M 331.8, 328.8
V 265.95
c 0-7,5.6-12.6,12.6-12.6
h 40.6
v 65.4
H 331.8
z"/>

<path data-map-id="1" style="fill: #d9534f" class="st3" 
d="
M 345.1, 302.4
V 276
c 0-3.5,2.8-6.3,6.3-6.3
h 20.3
v 32.7
H 345.1
z"/>


</svg>
</div>
</body></html>
```

However the simplest since we have a scalable object is scale up by 2 using a transform, and adjust viewport to suit.

```html
<html><head></head><body>
<div>
<svg width="325" height="250" viewBox="375 330 2 555" style="outline: 1px solid #666;">

<g transform="scale(2)">

 <path data-map-id="1" style="fill: #d9534f" class="st3" d="M345.1,302.4V276c0-3.5,2.8-6.3,6.3-6.3h20.3v32.7H345.1z"/>

</g>
</svg>

</div>
</body></html>
```